# Custom Payer Promotion

Tags: facebook-graph-api, customization, promotions

In order to implement a custom promotion unit I would need to know the specific amount Facebook will be giving the user for free.
Is there a way to determine the value of the current Facebook offer?

[Custom PP Unit Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/payer_promotion/#custom_pp_unit)